# Register multiple applications to the same custom protocol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with a custom protocol scheme, let's say example://
What I want to achieve is to register another application to this protocol, and when such a link is clicked display an application chooser to decide which app to open.

I've tried to accomplish this with URL Associations, unfortunately without any result. I did not found any meaningful documentation on how to do this using WPF-based applications.
The scheme is registered in HKCU/Software/Classes, according to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should write a application chooser and register it with the "example://" procooll.

Windows 10 does seem to have a concept of having multiple *potential* Applications for each  extension and protocoll. But as soon as it has "one to use as default", it will no longer ask for the selection. Only things like "Open with" will still ask wich of the candidates to use.

This has nothing to do with WPF. It is unlikely to even mater if you use a protocoll or file extension association. This is entirely a OS side thing.